How to call a Dart method from Js with WASM compability
Im go to Flutter 3.22.0 and want to use this with WASM, before migrating im write a package that now not exist
For example im have a method
@js.JSExport()
void onMapCl(double lat, double lon) {
  if (widget.onMapClick != null) {
    widget.onMapClick!(LatLng(lat, lon));
  }
}

And after
js_util.createDartExport(this); <-- not exist, because js_util dont exist with WASM

Before migrating used @js.JSExport() to class and methods, in html page i have
let appState = window.parent._appState;

And easy call flutter method
appState.onMapCl(_lat, _lon);


That is a pretty bleeding edge quesiton. I fear that no one on SO will be able to answer this. You probably have better chances to file an issue on https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk
